# Getting imagegrabscreen to work

Tags: php, gd, screenshot

I'm trying to get [`imagegrabscreen`](http://php.net/imagegrabscreen) (a GD function) to work with my Apache/Vista PC.

I'm using the following code:

```
<?php
$im = imagegrabscreen();

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

At the moment I get a solid black image, the size of my secondary monitor (1024*768). I'm using Apache 2.2, runing as a service, Vista SP1 with UAC off, PHP 5.2.8 and GD (information below). I've followed the note on the `imagegrabscreen` page about allowing Apache access to the desktop. I've also restarted the service and the apache server. I get the same results with `imagegrabwindow`.

Is this a bug (do other people have trouble running this method?) or is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
Array
(
    [GD Version] => bundled (2.0.34 compatible)
    [FreeType Support] => 1
    [FreeType Linkage] => with freetype
    [T1Lib Support] => 1
    [GIF Read Support] => 1
    [GIF Create Support] => 1
    [JPG Support] => 1
    [PNG Support] => 1
    [WBMP Support] => 1
    [XPM Support] => 
    [XBM Support] => 1
    [JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support] => 
)
```

**Apache Service Log On details:**

[http://www.kalleload.net/uploads/maogfnfnczfh.png http://www.kalleload.net/uploads/maogfnfnczfh.png](http://www.kalleload.net/uploads/maogfnfnczfh.png)

Comment: Just an random idea but have you tried disabling UAC?

Comment: I have that off. Apache is also running as the local user - presumably myself - and that is an Administrator user.

Comment: Is Apache running as a service, and with access to the display (was a check box in w2k)?

Comment: Apache is running as a service. I can't find any "access to display" checkboxes though. I'll post a screenshot of the Log On tab for the service.

Comment: It was the "allow service to interact with desktop" checkbox that I was referring to, which I see is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the source to imagegrabscreen();

at this point, I believe it is failing because we both have multi-monitor set-ups.

The current code calls GetDC(0), which according to
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144871(VS.85).aspx
should return the device context for "the entire screen", but 
"To get the DC for a specific display monitor,
use the EnumDisplayMonitors and CreateDC functions"

I am going to do a bit more testing of this and see if I can come up with multi-monitor-friendly code.

Comment: That's great news Hugh. If you do make a patch for it could you contact Pierre (irc.freenode.org #libgd) to ask about including it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think `imagegrabscreen()` only works in Windows XP not Vista.
You should check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabscreen.php)