# imagegrabscreen() not working / black image

Tags: php, image-processing

I'm trying

```
$im = imagegrabscreen();
imagepng($im, "1myscreenshot.png");
imagedestroy($im);
```

But I just get a black image

Can you please help me ?
Im using : Windows 7 ,  XAMPP 1.7.4 (PHP: 5.3.5)

thanks
jokonardi

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631449/getting-imagegrabscreen-to-work

Comment: im not understand that ...can you give me more detail please ..thanks before manseUk
I looked at the source to imagegrabscreen();

at this point, I believe it is failing because we both have multi-monitor set-ups.

The current code calls GetDC(0), which according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144871(VS.85).aspx should return the device context for "the entire screen", but "To get the DC for a specific display monitor, use the EnumDisplayMonitors and CreateDC functions"

I am going to do a bit more testing of this and see if I can come up with multi-monitor-friendly code.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Apache set to 'Allow service to interact with desktop'? If not this function will not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631449/getting-imagegrabscreen-to-work -> im try this but still not working