# take a screenshot of the current screen and save it as a png image through php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hello all I have an requirement that clients needs screenshot of current webpage when he clicks a button "sceencapture"
 Although i googled for it 
  result come out in this way

```
$im = imagegrabscreen();
imagepng($im, "myscreenshot.png");
imagedestroy($im);
```

in the manual on php.net link  [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabscreen.php)
having a note :This function is only available on Windows.
please help ..

Comment: So... what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Where is the PHP being run? If it's on a remote server then it will be trying to capture the screen of the server it's being run on. You'd need to run this locally (on windows). Here are some more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631449/getting-imagegrabscreen-to-work

Comment: i need to run on linux system

Comment: @RajeevRanjan - well then this method isn't possible. Try Erik's solution below.

Comment: I don't know what the exact requirements are but you might want to check out: CutyCapt a commandline tool which can 'capture WebKit's rendering of a web page' - http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 7):

This is not possible using PHP, as PHP executes on the server and a screenshot by definition must be done on the client. You could take a screenshot on the client side using client-side technology like the [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) library. Then you could send the screenshot to your server side PHP code if you wanted to.

Comment: I don't know just downvoted and why. This is exactly how you can do the task. I was just about to make the same answer +1

Comment: anyway @Erik Schierboom i will give a try to it.

Comment: it is said that it should  work ie9+ in the documentation  what about ie7 and ie8 have you used in your projects.

Comment: canvas are only supported ie9+, therefore it won't work with ie8-.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element#Support

Comment: In my opinion, you shouldn't worry about IE < 9. Even google refuses to support older versions. http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33864

Answer (score 3):

Although @Erix Schierboom answered the question I felt like sharing some code.

This cannot be done with `php` alone. You will need `javascript` to take the screenshot, convert it into a `string` and send it via `ajax` to a `php script` which would then save the content.

To do that you can use this library http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/.
Now the magic happens in the next few lines of code:

```
// an example html page
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascripts/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#screenshot').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                html2canvas($('body'), {
                    onrendered: function(canvas){
                        var imgString = canvas.toDataURL();
                        window.open(imgString);
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {
                                file: imgString
                            },
                            success: function(response){
                                //alert('Everything works fine.');
                            },
                            error: function(response){
                                //alert('Server response error.');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="width: 800px; margin: auto;">
    <input type="button" id="screenshot" value="Screenshot!"/>
    <div style="height: 100px;border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;">
        Big header!
    </div>
    <div style="height: 500px;border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;">
        Medium Content
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>



// Your php side script
<?php
if($_POST['file'] != "") {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $file = base64_decode(str_replace('data:image/png;base64,','',$_POST['file']));
    $im = imageCreateFromString($file);
    if($im){
        $save = imagepng($im, '/path/to/the/new/file.png');
        echo json_encode(array('file' => true));
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Could not parse image string.'));
    }
    exit();
}

?>
```

As far as the IE 7 & 8 support goes - google (and other giant web sites) have stated to support up to 1 version back from the latest. So, if the current version is 10, they will only support 9 and 10. I believe this is a good practice and I'm using it with my clients as well. IE < 8 is a big pain in the ... to be working with if you're developing advanced web pages. If your client still insists having IE 7 & 8 support, you may want to checkout [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) and [html5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv/) which may be able to help you bring the html5 support to IE.