# how to take screenshot in php codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

> Still i cant get any result can you help me?

i want take screenshot in my webpage. well i used code below showed:

```
<script>
window.ready = function () { alert("It's loaded!");
<?php
$img = imagegrabscreen();
imagepng($img, 'screenshot.png');
?> }
</script>
```

but it saved black image. what i do for it.?

i got code from  as link below:

click this link:

http://www.codedevelopr.com/articles/image-screenshots-php/

finally help me that
code as `PHP` or `script` to take screenshot and save that image.

if anyone show a way of answer for this problem.

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Website screenshots using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

Comment: how to integrate that ?

Comment: still i cant get any result

Comment: What have you tried with regards to the html2canvas library?  Can you post that code here?

Comment: that html2canvas using button action and without script file cant load, but i want taken screenshot after page fully loaded. i m already script files used so again use this scripts files conflict that page  so i cant use that.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631449/getting-imagegrabscreen-to-work), the fucntion will only work for XP and lower.

Please check your system preferences and maybe your logs for additional information.

Comment: here i m using OS as  `windows 7` and SERVER as `Apache server`

Comment: That's why I said, that your approch does only work with Windows XP and lower. You may have to find another solution for your feature request.

Comment: i cant get any result still now if you have any idea means pls share with me

Comment: Did you read the article? Your approach does not work with Windows7, etc. You may have a look at this project on Github: https://github.com/microweber/screen